# What could possibly be wrong in this IF-Conditional statement? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What could possibly be the error in this ??

```
int flag11 = 1;


if (([self.textField1.text length]>0) &&  
    ([self.textField4.text length]>0) && 
    ([self.textField3.text length]>0) && 
   (([self.textField2.text length]>0) || (flag11)))
    {
               NSLog(@"Please display me");

               // Some statements //
    }
```

Here, first three conditions are TRUE. And the last one should obviously be TRUE because of flag11 being 1.

It breaks out with error `Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)` and `Program received error:  SIGABRT` and does not enter inside `IF` statement as expected.

---

**Note:**   *If I remove `flag11`, and I have just those four conditions, it works! What I want to know is why does it report an error when `flag11` is added to the code.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird. I made a sample project with 4 textfields and a button hooked up to an action which does your check, and NSLog's the results and it seemed to work fine. Here's the code if you want to see:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {

  IBOutlet UITextField * textField1;
  IBOutlet UITextField * textField2;
  IBOutlet UITextField * textField3;
  IBOutlet UITextField * textField4;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * textField1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * textField2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * textField3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField * textField4;

- (IBAction)buttonPress;

@end

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize textField1;
@synthesize textField2;
@synthesize textField3;
@synthesize textField4;

- (void)dealloc; {
  [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; {
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField; {
  if(textField == textField1){
    [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else if(textField == textField2){
    [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else if(textField == textField3){
    [textField3 resignFirstResponder];
  }
  else{
    [textField4 resignFirstResponder];
  }
  return YES;
}

- (IBAction)buttonPress; {

  int flag11 = 1;

  if (([self.textField1.text length]>0) &&  
      ([self.textField4.text length]>0) && 
      ([self.textField3.text length]>0) && 
      (([self.textField2.text length]>0) || (flag11)))
  {
    NSLog(@"Please display me");

    // Some statements //
  }
  else{
    NSLog(@"Nothing");
  }
}

@end
```

One thing I got stuck on was that you put textField2 being the one that does not require any text. (lol) I guess the only thing to make sure is that the 4 textfields are hooked up to the right IBOutlet, and that the file's owner is the delegate for each one as well. Hope that helps!

Comment: Fill up textfields 1, 3, and 4 alone and try clicking it ?

Comment: Yeah, I filled textfields 1, 3, and 4, and then pressed the button which I hooked up to the - (IBAction)buttonPress; method, and it worked fine. I wonder why it's not working for you.

Comment: like i told you, he missed to wire it up correctly in iB, check textfield2 for sure

Answer (score 0):

SIGABRT means that you are trying to accessing something that isn't there. Did you created all the textfield's properly and/or drag the right connection in IB?

Comment: It's all done well ! If I remove flag 11, and I have just those four conditions, it works. What I want to know is why does it report an error when FLAG1 is added to the code.

Comment: waht about changing the last line to `... || (flag11 > 0)`?